# WP_Error on Tag and Archive Pages

Tags: php, wordpress, archive, slug, notice

I get the following error on Wordpress when i click on the archive or tag pages on my sidebar:

> Notice: Undefined property: WP_Error::$slug in
>   /opt/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-error.php on line 78

I don't know where i can look after it, but i think it's somewhere in archive.php. 
(We're using a custom theme, but i didn't code it). Maybe it also has something to do with the Plugin we use (its called: Ultimate Tag Cloud Widget)

Can someone help? (I can also post the whole archive.php file, if necessary)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Dear you just replace the old file(class-wp-error.php) in you error directory and then see what happend...

I got this issue recently and i just replace may file again from the previous back and its work out...

May be you also got the solution go to your error directory and paste the file...Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Maybe it's a stupid question, but with which file can i replace the old file?

Comment: The file that show error you i mean that class-wp-error.php file replace and then check again... Have you the back of file class-wp-error.php???